# How to escape ampersand in \acro command?

Tags: acronyms, ampersand

I am trying to use the acronym package to create an acronym list. The problem is that one of the acronyms I need to use contains an ampersand ('&').

But when I try to compile the .tex file I get this error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \&
l.2 ...&M}[\AC@hyperlink{M\&M}{M\&M}]{I like them}
```

Here is an example:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{M\&M}{I like them}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

So how do I use an ampersand in an acronym using the acronym package?

More generally, how is it possible to apply special formatting to a single acronym? For example

```
\acro{\textit{IAF}}{Italic acronym frenzy}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Completely different way than in my previous answer, is **reading the package documentation**, [for example here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{FoobAR(tm)}[FoobAR™]{Copyrighted}
\end{acronym}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{MM}[M\&M]{I like them}

\acro{IAF}[\textit{IAF}]{Italic acronym frenzy}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! This works for both the & and registered trademark symbols. I will be using this in my document.

Comment: @egreg +1 for `\textit` :)

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps not the best way to input it, but this works:

```
\acro{M\string&M}{I like them}
```

Comment: Great! It looks like it will work, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can define macros `\makeampletter` and `\makeampcolsep` similar to `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. This makes `&` to locally behave like a letter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{acronym}

\def\makeampletter{\catcode`\&11\relax} % <-- HERE
\def\makeampcolsep{\catcode`\&4\relax} % <-- HERE

\begin{document}

\tracingmacros=1
\begin{acronym}
\makeampletter % <-- HERE
\acro{M&M}{I like them}
\makeampcolsep % <-- HERE
\end{acronym}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
Just to test & that ampersand works
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Will this work on the registered trademark symbol?

Comment: At first I was sure it will work with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. But I tried and unsuccessfully. I'm unable to make it work, neither via unicode nor via command definition.