# italic acronym in \acro{PCB}{Printed Circuit Board}

Tags: acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape ampersand in \acro command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/how-to-escape-ampersand-in-acro-command)

Hello i would like to insert something like this `\acro{\textit{PCB}}{Printed Circuit Board}` inside acronym environment, but i get an error. Is there any way in printing a **single italic acronym**?

Comment: @tohecz [Your answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47334) seems to be what's needed here.

Comment: what package and document class are you using?  ([minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) would help.)

Comment: Please see the answer that **egreg** linked to in his comment.

Comment: I use `report` and package `acronym`, thats all.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina i did try that, but it is about trademark symbol. I dont get it.

Comment: @71GA: use the optional argument of `\acro`: something like `\acro{PCB}[\textit{PCB}]{Printed Circuit Board}`.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina It worked like a charm thank you.