# Hashtag in Acronym

Tags: acronyms

I am trying to setup my acronym list and I'm trying to use `C#` as an acronym but

```
\acro{C#}{Eine Programmiersprache von Microsoft}
```

Doesn't work since `#` is a reserved character so it gives the error

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. \acro{C#}

So I tried to escape it as `\#`. This also doesn't work however:

```
\acro{C\#}{Eine Programmiersprache von Microsoft}
```

> Missing \endcsname inserted. \acro{C\#}{Eine Programmiersprache von Microsoft}

I also googled `Missing \endcsname` which seems to be caused by an illegal character which has to be `\` here.

I also saw some answers about `catcode` but it was encouraged not to use it if there is another solution.
Is there another solution?
Or should I rather use `C Sharp` in the acronym list? And if so, how do I still use `C#` in the text?

Comment: Before your comment I did not, however it doesn't seem to work either. It's underlined in red with the commend `math command outside math env` and if I try to compile it I get the same error (`Missing \endcsname ...`) as when I try `\#`

Comment: You can't put special symbols in the first argument (the "label"). I guess you should use something like `\acro{Csharp}[C\#]{Eine Programmiersprache von Microsoft}` and then use `Csharp` as label.

Comment: @campa this works, thank you. To prevent that it uses the long text the first time I use the acronym I added `\acused{C Sharp}`. Mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm absolutely sure there is a duplicate but I couldn't find it.)

From the `acronym` documentation:

> In the `acronym` environment, acronyms are defined with the command:
>
> `\acro{<acronym>}[<short name>]{<full name>}`.
>
> The first argument
>   <*acronym*> is the acronym string itself and is used in the commands of
>   the previous section such as `\ac` or `\acl`, that print the different
>   forms of the acronym. Because internal commands take <*acronym*> for
>   storing the different forms of the acronym, the TEX code for the
>   acronym is limited by `\csname`. If the acronym requires problematic or
>   complicate TEX stuff (font commands, . . . ), then this code can be
>   given in the optional argument <*short name*>. The first argument
>   <*acronym*> is then a simpler string to identify the acronym. For
>   example, an acronym for water can look like this:
>
> `\acro{H2O}[$\mathrm{H_2O}$]{water}`
>
> Then `\acs{H2O}` gets H<sub>2</sub>O and
>   `\acl{H2O}` prints “water”.

The first argument of `\acro` is then like a label and as such should contain only characters allowed in `\csname...\endcsname`. The "complex" formatting (like, in this case, the sharp) can be passed as optional argument

```
\acro{Csharp}[C\#]{Eine Programmiersprache von Microsoft}
```

or

```
\acro{Csharp}[C$\sharp$]{Eine Programmiersprache von Microsoft}
```

For possible ways of typing the sharp please refer to [How to make the correct hash-symbol in C Sharp (C#)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44528/82917).

Comment: This Q/A is closely related, but is also specific to a particular character: [How to escape ampersand in \acro command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47318/579).  There seems to be a need for a more "generic" question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thx. I see I've upvoted that, but it's not the dupe I mean. I could swear _I've_ already copy/pasted the very same bit of the `acronym` doc for an answer, but I can't find it among mine. And there is not as many of them as in your case `:-)` Dunno, maybe it was only a draft I didn't post...

Comment: Well, if you *do* find a good, general Q/A on this topic, please add it to the "often referenced questions" list in meta.