# Acronyms with ampersand symbol?

Tags: symbols, acronyms

is it possible to use the ampersand symbol `&` inside acronyms?

```
\begin{acronym}
\acro{ACC S&G}{Adaptive Cruise Control Stop and Go}
\end{acronym}
```

And inside my text i used:

```
\acs{ACC S&G}
```

The error that occurs is `missing \endcsname inserted`. It doesn't work. Also I tried it with `\&` without any success.

Comment: Incorrect use of `&`. Change to `\&`.

Comment: \& doesn not work inside acro and \acs or \ac. The acronym don not get linked. It looks like there doesn`t exist this acronym.

Comment: Please provide a MWE so we can better assist you.

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47318

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you very much. The solution was 
        \acro{ACC SG}[ACC S\&G]{Adaptive Cruise Control Stop and Go}